# How to sort list of objects that having foreign key in django?

Tags: python, django, sorting

I want to sort the List of `User` objects based on the `Bank` balance

**Model User**

```
Class User(model.Model):
    name,
    birthday
    ...
```

**Model Bank**

```
Class Bank(model.Model):
    user = model.OneToOneField('user.User')
    balance = model.IntegerField()
    ...
```

**Data**

```
User has 2 objects `Username 1` and `Username2`

Bank has 2 objects:
    - object1:
        - user: user1
        - balance: 5000

    - object2:
        - user: user2
        - balance: 3000
```

**List of objects** `user_list`

```
[<User: User 1>, <User: User 2>]
```

If I do `sorted(user_list)` it will return same list, but I want it sorted based on Bank.balance so the list should be `[<User: User 2>, <User: User 1>]`. How should I do it?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
users = Bank.objects.all().values_list('user').order_by('balance')
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered of low-quality.  Could you add some explanation to make the rationale behind the solution clearer?